# Webserver vhost configuration in database?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, nginx, lighttpd, virtualhost

I know it's possible with lighttpd, but is there a way to achieve the same thing with Apache or better yet, nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why yes, [`mod_dbd_vhost`](http://code.google.com/p/dbd-modules/wiki/mod_vhost_dbd) can do this.